# Will my kernel module be reloaded after system reboot?

Tags: kernel-module

I'm starting a "Hello World" module, but I'm afraid to do some kind of error.
If I break my system for some reason will my module be reloaded at reboot (crashing again my system)?

I guess it won't, but I prefer to be certain.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, kernel modules are autoloaded only as an answer to events or requests. Just don't link your module on (common) hardware.

For testing modules, you don't need to install the module ("install" as to put the module into the right public location). You should install the module from the build directory (here "install" as loading the module in memory and link it to kernel).

But in any case, keep always a working kernel available in your preferred boot loader (and this is a MUST for all users)